# Most efficient way to calculate nutrients

Tags: math, calculator

I am creating a macronutrient calculator for a project, however I'm not sure on the best way to do the math.  The goal is to get a bunch of foods (using grams) to add up to 190 grams of protein, 300 grams of carbs, and 50 grams of fat.

For example, I can use grams of Chicken Breast which contain .3057 grams of protein and .035 grams of fat per gram of chicken breast. Ground Turkey is also an option which contains .1851g protein and .0705g fat per gram. Brown rice contains .229g carbs, .025g protein,and .009g fat per gram. Oats contain .69g carbs, .065g fat, and .13g protein per gram. Natural peanut butter has .5g fat, .25g protein, and .22g carbs per gram.

I'm trying to figure out how to get to the specified nutrient goals without making the program really slow. I'm kind of at a loss right now.  Just an idea or concept on how to do this would help me greatly, I don't expect someone else to write this for me.  Would this be a better question to ask on Math.StackExchange?

Comment: Probably not suitable for the Math Stack Exchange. As it is, it might not be suitable for here. You might want to try something then, if you have a problem, edit your question (or create a new one) with what problems you faced.

Comment: There is a lot of previous work applying *linear programming* to the problem of achieving a nutritionally-balanced diet at minimum cost.